# Не верно работает метод сортировки

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не верно работает метод сортировки, куда-то пропадает цифра `5`. На языке Pascal всё работает (код переводил с максимальной точностью).

```
class test {
    protected static int a, b;
    protected static int[] array = {
        2,
        21,
        42,
        43,
        567,
        5
    };
    protected static final int ARRAY_LENGTH = array.length;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH - 1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < ARRAY_LENGTH - 2; j++) {
                a = array[j];
                b = array[j + 1];

                if(a > b) {
                  array[j] = b;
                  array[j + 1] = a;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
          System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вр внутреннем цикле

```
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < ARRAY_LENGTH - 2; j++) {
            a = array[j];
            b = array[j + 1];

            if(a > b) {
              array[j] = b;
              array[j + 1] = a;
            }
        }
    }
```

максимальный индекс элемента, к котором может быть обращение, равен `ARRAY_LENGTH - 2`. Поэтом последний элемент массива остается "неприкасаемым":)

Представьте, что размер массива равен 2. В этом случае `ARRAY_LENGTH - 2` будет равно 0. В результате внутренний цикл ни разу не выполнится, и массив из двух элементов не будет отсортирован.

И, кроме того, в этом цикле вы также неправильно указали верхнюю  границу индекса, поэтому, опять-таки последний элемент массива не выводится.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
```

И если вы ввели константу `ARRAY_LENGTH`, то и пользуйтесь ее везде вместо члена класса `length`.
Должно быть

```
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, во внутреннем цикле Вы не сравниваете два последних элемента массива, так как `j < ARRAY_LENGTH - 2`.

Во вторых, при выводе элементов массива на экран, Вы выводите все элементы, за исключением последнего, так как у Вас `i < array.length - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Последний элемент массива у вас теряется тут

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
```

и тут

```
for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH - 1; i++) {
```

Зачем вы отнимаете от длины единицу, если и так сравниваете оператором "строго меньше"?

Comment: я не пропускаю, потому что счетчик у массивов начинается с нуля, т.е. если длина массива 2, и мне нужно получить последний элемент (второй), мне нужно отнять от длины единицу (2 - 1 = 1).

Comment: @ikerya, Только вот в условии у Вас *строго* больше. Если Вы вычитаете единицу, то условие должно быть больше или равно, а не строго больше.

Comment: @ikerya вот только ваш цикл, на двух элементах выполнится всего один раз - для i=0, потому-что на следующей итерации у вас i=1, а условия выхода i<(2-1) => i<1

Answer (score 0):

Вот вся логика вашего приложения.

```
int[] arr = new int[]{90,123,12,0,1,4,7,44,-2,-4,-5};
    int a = 0;
    int max = -50;
    int imax = -50;
    max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){//Выполняется пока не кончаться элементы массива.

        for(a = i; a<arr.length;a++){//Находит максимальный элемент
            max = -50;
            if(max<arr[a]) {
                max = arr[a];//Меняет максимальный элемент
                imax = a;//Запоминает  какой элемент массива максимальный
            }
            if(arr[i]<max){//Сравниваем максимальный элемент с текущим если он меньше то заменяем значения
                arr[imax]=arr[i];//Максимальный элемент = текущему
                arr[i] = max;//Текущий равен максмимальному
            }
        }
    }


    for (int ac = 0; ac<arr.length;ac++){
        System.out.println(arr[ac]+"   ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы, наверное, меня не так поняли, мне не нужен чужой код (тем более тут по убиванию, если я правильно понял). У меня куда-то девается пятерка

Comment: Так как это последний элемент, вы его пропускаете  в данном   коде:
for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH - 1; i++)